# How to read HttpInputStream twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

I need to parse and custom save(not using `SaveAs`) `HttpPostedFileBase` in my asp.net mvc application.

My code is:

```
private ReportViewModel LoadFile(Stream stream, string fileName)
{
   MapParser mapParser = new MapParser(stream);
   try
   {
       mapParser.Parse();
   }
   ....
   stream.position = 0;
   SaveFile(memStream2, Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/Maps/" +
                (map.Id + "." + ext)));
   ....
}

public static void SaveFile(Stream inputStream, string filePath)
{
   using (Stream file = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
   {
      inputStream.CopyTo(file);
   }
 }


LoadFile(loadMapVM.MapFile.InputStream, loadMapVM.MapFile.FileName)
```

So, my `Parse()` method works fine, but after that `SaveAs` method create file with 0 bytes.
I think, that I should clone or reopen to start my stream after `Parse()`. But how can I do that?

**EDIT**

My MapParser code:

```
        public MapParser(Stream stream)
        {
            using(stream)
            {
                IWorkbook workBook = null;

                if (POIXMLDocument.HasOOXMLHeader(stream))
                    workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);

                if (POIFSFileSystem.HasPOIFSHeader(stream))
                    workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);

                if (workBook == null)
                    throw new MapParserException(MapParserError.InvalidFileFormat);

                mSheet = workBook.GetSheetAt(0);
            }
        }

    public void Parse()
    {
        mData = new Map();

        mData.UnitCode = mSheet.GetRow(0).GetCell(5).GetSafeValue();
        if (mData.UnitCode == "")
            throw new MapParserException(MapParserError.NoUnitCode, 0, 5);

        ....
    }
```

Comment: If it is possible, you can first save file to a temp location. Then open a file stream to temp file and try parsing. If parsing fails delete temp file, if it passes move file to its permanent location. It would be more efficient.

Comment: Could we see the code for MapParser, what is it doing to the stream? Otherwise, why not try saving the stream first, then resetting the steam position to 0 and using the MapParser?

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, it should not be assumed that `Stream`s are repeatable; this applies *in particular* when talking about data coming over the wire. If you read the data in `Parse`, then *you have consumed the data*: it is gone.

Options:

- buffer all the data in memory (`Stream.CopyTo` into a `MemoryStream`) - possible if you restrict it to moderate sizes, but not a good option if the data could be huge
- perform the `Parse` *while writing* to the file-system; efficient but difficult to implement
- buffer the data to *disk* (basically do the `SaveFile` *first*), then check the contents that you wrote (write it to a different location, then delete the file if the contents are no good, or move the file if the contents are fine)

Comment: Thanks, no I got not big data. As far as I`m concerned, I need to copy my stream into MemoryStream, but after Parse, when I set position to 0 I got exception, that my stream is already closed

Comment: "If you read the data in Parse, then you have consumed the data: it is gone."
But if I called stream.SaveAs after Parse - it works good.